# Button inside a MenuItem won't open Sub-MenuItems

Tags: wpf, button, menuitem, routedevent

I have a `Button` inside a `MenuItem.Header` like this:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Button>Hello</Button>
        </MenuItem.Header>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem2"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

[image]

if I click the `MenuItem` *outside* the `Button`, the sub-menu opens. But if I click the `Button` the sub-menu will not open. I believe that's because the event of the clicked is not passed to the `MenuItem`. How do I fix it?

In short -  I want the sub-menu to open when clicking the `Button`.

(The use is mainly for styling purposes, I have a button style and I want to use it as a `MenuItem`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Button` doesn't know how to expand a `MenuItem` unless you tell it how to by writing some code:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Hello</Button>
        </MenuItem.Header>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="SubItem2"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

---

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    MenuItem mi = btn.Parent as MenuItem;
    if (mi != null)
        mi.IsSubmenuOpen = !mi.IsSubmenuOpen;
}
```

Comment: I guess it would work but I want to avoid using code behind to sustain MVVM architecture pattern. Isn't there a general solution to pass event to parent?

Comment: "Pass event to parent" without writing some code? Certainly not. Also, how a MenuItem is expanded is not the responsibility of a view model. This is purely view-based functionality.

Comment: Sounds logical but I've been told that in MVVM the View should only be in XAML and you shouldn't write code behind. Is that a bad paradigm?

Comment: That's not true. MVVM is not about eliminating *view-related* code from the views. It's about separatation of concerns. In fact, you could write an entire view programmatically without violating the MVVM pattern if you wanted to. But that's another story that doesn't have anything to do with your original question.

Comment: OK! Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (I have *MaterialDesignInXAML* activated so it looks different but it's the same).

I did it the reverse way of your example: create a button detached of the menu and hide the menu itself.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Menu>
        <!-- Set width=0 to hide the menu -->
        <MenuItem Width="0" x:Name="myMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Settings"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Button Content="Try me">
        <b:Interaction.Triggers>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <b:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myMenu}" PropertyName="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True"/>
            </b:EventTrigger>
        </b:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]